# How to disable all the autostarting apps

Tags: startup, android

How I can programmatically find the list of applications that starts on device startup. Is there any way to **programmatically** disable autostarting applications you don't need.

Thanks

Comment: this question should be asked on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Other than removing the offending applications, there's no way to do that.

The API says the system has to honor requests for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast that any application puts in its manifest.  Since there are uses for `BOOT_COMPLETED` beyond starting long-running services, shutting off that mechanism would break the API and cause some programs to malfunction.

Edit to answer the first part of the question:  The `PackageManager` can get you a list of all receivers that can receive the broadcast, but you're still powerless to do anything about it.

Comment: I also think in the same way to remove apps but lots of System Apps are there which starts on startup and I cant remove those applications. There must be some other way to manage that.